# Wait for All the <iframe>s to finish loading in React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, iframe, react-redux

I'm using the embed iframe from Spotify to show the top tracks of artists in my app:

https://repotify.netlify.app/

When the search is `pending` a loading spinner is shown until resolved and the same thing happens when the top tracks are being fetched and `pending`.

But when I render the iframe of each top 10 tracks they start to load and show the box-shadow on page before fully loading:

[image]

This is the code for that component:

```
const TopTracks = ({ track }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <iframe
        src={`https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/${track.id}`}
        title={track.name}
        width="300"
        height="80"
        allowtransparency="true"
        allow="encrypted-media"
        className="tracks"
      ></iframe>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TopTracks;
```

What I would like to happen is for the iframes to load completely and then show all at once and while loading, show a spinner like the rest of fetch requests:

[image]

This is the functionality for the trackList which maps over the tracks and gets the IDs for each:

```
// Imports

const TrackList = () => {
  const artistTopTracks = useSelector(selectArtistTopTracks);
  const topTracksIsLoading = useSelector(selectTopTracksIsLoading);
  const topTracksHasError = useSelector(selectTopTracksHasError);
  const searchIsLoading = useSelector(selectSearchIsLoading);
  const searchHasError = useSelector(selectSearchHasError);

  if (topTracksIsLoading || searchIsLoading) return <IsLoading />;
  if (topTracksHasError || searchHasError) return <HasError />;

  return (
    <div>
      {!artistTopTracks
        ? ""
        : artistTopTracks.map((track) => (
            <TopTracks key={track.id} track={track} />
          ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default TrackList;
```

Is there a way I can show the loading spinner until all the iframes are loaded?

If not, is there a way to at least not show that shadow-box of each when they're rendering individually?

Comment: here is a pretty similar idea: https://medium.com/@josh.j.pearson/handling-iframe-loading-in-react-57f044a9d0fa If the article will not help, could you create a playground with minimal functionality of your application?

Comment: @ŹmicierJaraševič Thanks, I'll check it out. This is the link to my app so you can see the functionality: https://repotify.netlify.app/

Comment: @ŹmicierJaraševič I tried what the article stated but that isn't really functional. I get a spinner next to each of the tracks (NOT INSTEAD OF THE TRACKS), while the tracks are being loaded.

Comment: could you create a playground on codesanbox.io or elsewhere? From my understanding, there is only one thing left - to combine all `onLoad` callbacks in a single place: store, promise.all, etc

Comment: @ŹmicierJaraševič Unfortunately I can't make a playground because this is using OAuth and I can't get an access point if I were to put the code there.